# CSS Transition does not apply to background

Tags: html, css, background, css-transitions, css-animations

my problem is weird but simple. I got a div with a class `navbaritem` and for some reason the transition-rule applies to the margin but not to the background.

Here's the HTML and CSS

```css
* {
    font-family: Raleway, Century Gothic;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

header > ul > li {
    margin-bottom: 5vh;
}

.navbaritem {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30vw;
    height: 6vh;
    margin-left: -8vw;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-30deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-30deg);
    
    background: rgb(245,246,246);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(245,246,246,1) 0%, rgba(219,220,226,1) 21%, rgba(184,186,198,1) 49%, rgba(221,223,227,1) 80%, rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(245,246,246,1) 0%,rgba(219,220,226,1) 21%,rgba(184,186,198,1) 49%,rgba(221,223,227,1) 80%,rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(245,246,246,1) 0%,rgba(219,220,226,1) 21%,rgba(184,186,198,1) 49%,rgba(221,223,227,1) 80%,rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f5f6f6', endColorstr='#f5f6f6',GradientType=0);
    
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.navbaritem:hover {
    margin-left: -3vw;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.navbaritem > a {
    height: 80%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: -10%;
    width: 90%;
    background: url(../img/graystripes.jpg);
    box-shadow: inset 3vh 1vh 3vh #000;
    -webkit-transform: skew(30deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(30deg);
    -o-transform: skew(30deg);
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4vh;
}


.navbaritem:hover {
    transition: 0.4s ease;
    
    background: rgb(255,0,0);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(247,0,0,1) 21%, rgba(137,0,0,1) 49%, rgba(247,0,0,1) 80%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(247,0,0,1) 21%,rgba(137,0,0,1) 49%,rgba(247,0,0,1) 80%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(247,0,0,1) 21%,rgba(137,0,0,1) 49%,rgba(247,0,0,1) 80%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#ff0000',GradientType=0);
}

.navbaritem > i {
    font-size: 5vh;
    color: #444;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 85%;
    
    -webkit-transform: skew(30deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(30deg);
    -o-transform: skew(30deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">            
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/hover.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900">

        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="navbaritem">
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="navbaritem">
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                        <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="navbaritem">
                        <a href="#">Pricing</a>
                        <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="navbaritem">
                        <a href="#">References</a>
                        <i class="fa fa-flag"></i>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <!--<div class="navbaritem">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            </div>-->
        </header>
        
        <main>

        </main>
        
        <footer>
            
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gradients are like images and so you cannot transition them directly. You could try some of the approaches mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918470/how-to-animate-gradient-background-smoothly/33938639#33938639

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am concerned you can't transition gradients. One approach would be to use 2 elements at the exact same position and apply your 2 different gradients, respectively. Then give one element an opacity of 1 (The one with the gradient you want to show by default) and then fade the opacity of that element to 0 and the other to 1 when hovered. However I wouldn't recommend this.

**EDIT** I found a workaround here: [Use CSS3 transitions with gradient backgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212/use-css3-transitions-with-gradient-backgrounds)

Comment: Could you give me feedback on my answer? Did my solution work or the linked workaround? :)

Comment: Sorry, although I read your comment after the Edit, your way worked, I now have 2 divs with one of them going opacity: 100% on hover.