# need help creating a loading bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a loading bar, just like in [monkey type](https://monkeytype.com) when it's 'downloading your data and applying settings'. I just want to make the bar, and the orange gradient move from the leftmost to the right.

I tried using a linear gradient for this, but it seems that it just flips between the two states ( which is also random).

```css
body {
    background: black;
}

.line {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: auto;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, orange, grey);
    border-radius: 25px;
    animation: gradual 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes gradual {
    0% {
        background: linear-gradient(to right, 0% orange, 100% grey);
    }

    100% {
        background: linear-gradient(to right, 100% orange, 0% grey);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class='line'></div>
```

Comment: This answer seems to be doing something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38173276/2181514 - only be animated the background-position.  Might be an alternative solution for you.

Comment: And this answer explains why your approach won't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918470/how-to-animate-gradient-background-smoothly "*linear gradients are not transitionable or animatable unlike colors (background-color) because they are considered as image*"

Comment: What is "monkey type"? Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, _specific_ question.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button it triggers the move() function which then gets the elem element from the document. It makes variables, width and id. If the width is below 100, it's going to make the width go +1. if it's above 100, it's going to not change the progress bar. The CSS styles the progress bar to make the gradient and make it look good.

You can achieve an animated loading bar using javascript `setTimeout`, adjust the timeout to change the speed that the progress bar increases. Here's a snippet demonstrating this approach with a linear gradient.

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#myBar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, orange, black);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>progress bar click button</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">click the button</button>
```

Comment: One thing about SO is that new users tend not to tag well.  The ask page *implies* that you should add *five* tags (actually says up-to) so it looks like more tags is better.  OP probably has some [tag:javascript] on their page but has actually asked about [tag:css].  I (personally) wouldn't downvote for a js answer given the tags, but others might as it looks like they want a css answer.  Just my tuppence on a potential reason for the downvote.

Comment: Line breaks should not be used for spacing. That's not their purpose.

Comment: `<br>` thats what he means